# How To define arguments in ironpython for the Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO.Scripter.Script Class

Tags: python, sql-server, ironpython, smo

I want to script my database objects using the ironpython code below:

```
import sys
import clr

database_name  = r'localhost\SQLEXPRESS'
dir_assemblies = r'D:\programfiles\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies'

# Import SMO Namespace
sys.path.append(dir_assemblies)
clr.AddReferenceToFile('Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll')
import Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo as SMO


db       = SMO.Server(database_name)
scripter = SMO.Scripter(db)

for database in db.Databases:
    for table in database.Tables:
        # TypeError: expected Array[Urn], got Table
        scripter.Script(table)
```

When executing this code, I get the following error:

```
File "SMOtest2.py", line 18, in <module>
TypeError: expected Array[Urn], got Table
```

The SMO.Scripter.**doc** gives me the following information:

```
Script(self: Scripter, urns: Array[Urn]) -> StringCollection
Script(self: Scripter, list: UrnCollection) -> StringCollection
Script(self: Scripter, objects: Array[SqlSmoObject]) -> StringCollection
```

I tried creating an Array[Urn] or an Array[SqlSmoObject] but without any succes.

Does anyone have an idea how I can create the right argument for the SMO.Scripter.Script Class?

I want to write the VB code below in python.
Taken from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162160(v=SQL.90).aspx

```
'Connect to the local, default instance of SQL Server.
Dim srv As Server
srv = New Server
'Reference the AdventureWorks database.
Dim db As Database
db = srv.Databases("AdventureWorks")
'Define a Scripter object and set the required scripting options.
Dim scrp As Scripter
scrp = New Scripter(srv)
scrp.Options.ScriptDrops = False
scrp.Options.WithDependencies = True
'Iterate through the tables in database and script each one. Display the script.
'Note that the StringCollection type needs the System.Collections.Specialized namespace to be included.
Dim tb As Table
Dim smoObjects(1) As Urn
For Each tb In db.Tables
    smoObjects = New Urn(0) {}
    smoObjects(0) = tb.Urn
    If tb.IsSystemObject = False Then
        Dim sc As StringCollection
        sc = scrp.Script(smoObjects)
        Dim st As String
        For Each st In sc
            Console.WriteLine(st)
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution:

```
arg=System.Array[SMO.SqlSmoObject]([table])
```

The full script looks like:

```
import sys    
import clr    
# import .NET Array
import System.Array

database_name  = r'localhost\SQLEXPRESS'    
dir_assemblies = r'D:\programfiles\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies'   

# Import SMO Namespace    
sys.path.append(dir_assemblies)    
clr.AddReferenceToFile('Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll')    
import Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo as SMO    


db       = SMO.Server(database_name)    
scripter = SMO.Scripter(db)    

for database in db.Databases:    
    for table in database.Tables:    
        # create a .NET Array as an argument for the scripter
        arg=System.Array[SMO.SqlSmoObject]([table])
        script = scripter.Script(arg)
        #output script
        for line in script:
            print line
```

Answer (score 0):

Never used IronPython or SMO, but it looks like it expects a collection of some sort. Have you tried:

```
scripter.Script(database.Tables)
```

instead of scripting one table at a time?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion but unfortunately without success. (see my answer below)

Comment: I was expecting the overload accepting `Array[SqlSmoObject]` to be called. Maybe try converting the `TableCollection` to an `Array[Table]` first.